# What is the "Chili sauce" ingredient in this recipe?

Tags: substitutions, sauce, ingredient-selection

I want to make this [Copy Cat A1 Steak Sauce](http://www.grouprecipes.com/87237/copy-cat-a1-steak-sauce.html#) but I'm not exactly sure what one ingredient is.

What is it calling for when it says **Chili sauce**?

Also, if it turns out I don't have the chili sauce they are referring to, are there good substitutions for it?

Comment: Might be Tabasco. The recipe being for A1, I wouldn't expect anything **hot** like Habaneros or even Sriracha sauce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heinz and some other companies sell a product that they call 'chili sauce', which might be what you're looking for.

It's a tomato-based sauce, with some spices and seasoning, but it's not particularly spicy.

If you have access to Dutch & German ingredients, you might replace it with one of the thicker shashlik sauces (aka 'curry ketchup').  If you have access to UK ingredients, you might try brown sauce.

If you wanted to make it yourself from scratch, see http://www.food.com/recipe/heinz-chili-sauce-copycat-457947

Comment: Great answer, Joe. Prepared Heinz "chili sauce" product is my best guess too.

Answer (score 0):

That recipe will make a Heinz 57 clone.

A1 is essentially thickened Worcestershire sauce.

However if you want to make Heinz 57, the. Use Heinz chili sauce.

Comment: I looked and saw that A1 had garlic and this recipe didn't have any.  I figured it would be a bit different but I didn't think it would be closer to Heinz57.